# Using susy in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, susy

I am using Rails 4.2.5. And I want to use susy.

I've installed some gems required,

```
gem 'susy'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'compass-susy-plugin'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
```

And in `config/application.rb`, I've added

```
require 'susy'
```

In `application.scss`

```
@import "susy";
```

But I failed to import susy in my scss file. When I give the command `sass --watch application.scss:application.css`, it shows `error application.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Susy and Compass installed with ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819588/getting-susy-and-compass-installed-with-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I may found the answer myself.
Actually, there's no need to convert scss file to css file since the gems we've installed will do that job for us.
By the way, upgrading the compass-rails gem to master may avoid some problem. See this [issue](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails/issues/70).